# Spring MVC: Creating View within Controller Runtime

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have an application written JSP/Servlets that I am migrating to Spring MVC. All goes fine until I encounter a specific problem. My application displays arbitrary XML files with Text Boxes and File Pickers based on special properties of the Nodes. With Servlets I traversed the XML and built the HTML based on it. With Spring MVC all the views are JSP which does NOT have this flexibility. It's so dynamic that it's completely static for my needs.
How can I dynamically build a view with Spring MVC within a controller class?

Example:

```
<Sample>
    <Field1>
        <Type>String</Type> <!-- Will be a TextBox on the view -->
        <Value>{@NS}</Value> <!-- NS :: Not Set -->
    </Field1>
    <Field2>
        <Type>Nested</Type> <!-- The value tag is a nested Field!
        <Value>
            <Field21>
                <Type>Object</Type> <!-- File Picker. The value of this node is base64 str of file -->
                <Value>...</Value>
            </Field21>
            <Field22>
                <Type>StringArray</Type> <!-- More Value tags can occur. A Plus sign on UI -->
                <!-- Already set within view -->
                <Value>V1</Value>
                <Value>V2</Value>
                ...
            </Field22>
            ...
        </Value>
    </Field2>
    ...
</Sample>
```

An XML like this comes in. It can have N field and can be nested M times. Arbitrary XML completely random not static at all. No common parts so statically created view as JSP can't be used. Instead I used Servlet to create a JSP runtime and bind the values the controls to the correct XML node. As result something like this can occur on the view:

```
Field1: [------------]
Field2:
    Field21: [-----------] [Browse]
    Field22: [-----------]
             [-----------] [+]
```

So in this case, my Model is my actual XML Document. My Controller is what processes the XML and creates a view from it, possibly by binding the two together so when the View is submitted the Model gets updated and the original XML is changed in the DB. At least this is what my current solution does with Servlets. I want to do the same thing with Spring MVC. Dynamic View creation. Something like:

AbstractView.jsp

```
 <_html>
        <_body>
            <_form ...>
                <_div><!-- Load dynamically generated content here... --></_div>
            </_form>
        <_/body>
    </_html>
```

An alternative approach would look like this. I have an abstractview jsp file that defined the common parts for all possible views. That's basically everything but the actual content that's completely dynamic.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to build a custom view from a standard layout everytime a specific method in a controller is called?

Comment: More or less correct. There is no standard layout. There is nothing. The user uploads an XML and I process it and have to display it. I'll update the post with a basic example.

Comment: Yes please, a example will go a long way to helping the community figure out the problem.

Comment: Added example. Quite basic, but clarifies my intention.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is not adapted to a JSP view. JSP view is for a static structure in which you add data from a model. Your model is way too complicated for a JSP.

For your example, I would stick more closely to your previous servlet solution, and have the controller directly generate the response and return NULL to say response is already completed. After all, in a servlet + JSP architecture, servlets normally only put data in request attributes that are displayed in the JSPs.

An alternative would be to create a custom View + View resolver pair. But honestly I cannot say whether it would not be more hard to write for a little gain. I have no experience on that part.